# howto add a static library (.a) into a C++ program?

Tags: c++, linker

I want to know how I can use a static library in C++ which I created, first the lib:

```
// header: foo.h
int foo(int a);
```

.

```
// code: foo.cpp
#include foo.h
int foo(int a)
{
    return a+1;
}
```

then I compile the library first:

1. g++ foo.cpp
2. ar rc libfoo.a foo.o

now I want to use these library in some file like:

```
// prog.cpp
#include "foo.h"
int main()
{ 
    int i = foo(2);
    return i;
}
```

how must I compile these now?
I made:

```
g++ -L. -lfoo prog.cpp
```

but get an error because the function foo would not be found

Comment: `g++ -L. -lfoo prog.cpp libfoo.a` IIRC

Comment: @sehe: -lfoo is approximately equivalent to listing libfoo.a on the command line. The order does matter though.

Answer (score 21):

You want:

```
g++ -L.  prog.cpp -lfoo
```

Unfortunately, the ld linker is sensitive to the order of libraries. When trying to satisfy undefined symbols in prog.cpp, it will only look at libraries that appear AFTER prog.cpp on the command line.

You can also just specify the library (with a path if necessary) on the command line, and forget about the -L flag:

```
g++ prog.cpp libfoo.a
```

Comment: Right, and in case the asker wants to know why, [this link](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_18.html) explains in pretty concise terms about linker order being left-to-right.  (Ah, after I added this comment, the answerer added a little supplementary info).